# How to summarize SQL search result of column B as sum based on data in column A?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have created an SQL formula to search for the time spent on a signal status for specific machines:

```
SELECT 'Core' as Core, Z.EventName, ISNULL(DIFF,0) AS DIFF 
FROM (select distinct MacID, EventName from dbo.tblMachine a  
join (SELECT DISTINCT EVENTNAME FROM dbo.tblEvtDur) 
b on b.EventName <> '' and MacID in ('A06','A07', 'A08', 'A09', 'B01','B05','B09', 'B10', 'B11', 'C04', 'C08', 'C09') ) 
z LEFT JOIN (SELECT A.MacID, A.EventName, SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, A.STARTdt, A.eNDdt)) 
as diff,round(SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, A.STARTdt, A.eNDdt)) / cast(aVG(Tdiff) 
as decimal(30,8)),4) * 100 AS PER FROM dbo.tblEvtDur  A 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT macid, SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, STARTdt, eNDdt)) as Tdiff 
FROM  dbo.tblEvtDur  WHERE DayID between '20180401' and '20180430'  
GROUP BY MacID ) B ON  A.MacID = B.MacID 
WHERE DayID between '20180401' and '20180430'  
AND A.MacID in
 ('A06','A07', 'A08', 'A09', 'B01','B05','B09', 'B10', 'B11', 'C04', 'C08', 'C09') 
group by A.MacID, A.EventName) a 
ON A.EVENTNAME = Z.EVENTNAME  and Z.MacID  = a.MacID order by Z.MacID, Z.EventName
```

What I got as a result was as seen here:

[image]

Now I want to have the SQL show me the sum total of EventName BLK, MDL, MTL, OFF, RPR, and RUN, for these specific machines. Is that possible?

Edit:

If I try adding a sum with group by clause, it doesn't work on the current SQL.

So I had to reconstruct it into so:

```
select 'Core' as Core, EventName, sum(DATEDIFF(second, startdt, EndDT)) as DIFF 
from dbo.tblEvtDur

where MacID in ('A06','A07','A08','A09','B01','B05','B09','B10','B11','C04','C08','C09')

and DayID between '20180531' and '20180531'

group by eventname
```

But depending on the day, certain signals will not appear so it is not listed in the result table.

[image]

What should I add to tell SQL to show me EventName BLK as 0?

Edit 2:

So far tried Dan's suggestion of using right join:

```
select 'Core' as [Core], a.EventName, isnull((sum(DATEDIFF(second, startdt, EndDT))),0) as DIFF 
from dbo.tblEvtDur a
right join (select distinct eventname from dbo.tblEvtDur where EventName in     
('BLK', 'MDL', 'MTL', 'OFF', 'RPR', 'RUN')) b 
on a.EventName = b.EventName
where MacID in ('A06','A07', 'A08', 'A09', 'B01','B05',
'B09', 'B10', 'B11', 'C04', 'C08', 'C09')
and DayID between '20180531' and '20180531'
group by a.eventname
```

Again, same results but time taken is significantly longer.

Comment: You can right join a list of unique EventName's onto your query: `RIGHT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT EventName from dbo.tblMachine) AS names ON yourPreviousQuery.EventName = names.EventName` and then use `ISNULL` to convert the `NULL` values to `0`

Comment: I should also mention that dbo.tblMachine does not contain EventName column it is only exclusive in dbo.tblEvtDur. Must have entered that in by mistake...

Comment: use b.EventName in place of a.EventName in your right join query. You are using using a.EventName that's why it is giving you same result.

Comment: Do you mean replace `group by a.eventname` with `group by b.eventname` ? Because I tried that and I get another message `Column 'dbo.tblEvtDur.EventName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.` What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregate function (sum, count, avg...) with group by.

```
 select count(*) from (output of your query) group by EventName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit hard to read because of the formatting but as @Piyush Ghediya answered you can use sum with a group by clause.

```
SELECT 'Core' as Core, Z.EventName, Sum(ISNULL(DIFF,0)) AS DIFF 
FROM (select distinct MacID, EventName from dbo.tblMachine a  
join (SELECT DISTINCT EVENTNAME FROM dbo.tblEvtDur) 
b on b.EventName <> '' and MacID in ('A06','A07', 'A08', 'A09', 'B01','B05','B09', 'B10', 'B11', 'C04', 'C08', 'C09') ) 
z LEFT JOIN (SELECT A.MacID, A.EventName, SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, A.STARTdt, A.eNDdt)) 
as diff,round(SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, A.STARTdt, A.eNDdt)) / cast(aVG(Tdiff) 
as decimal(30,8)),4) * 100 AS PER FROM dbo.tblEvtDur  A 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT macid, SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, STARTdt, eNDdt)) as Tdiff 
FROM  dbo.tblEvtDur  WHERE DayID between '20180401' and '20180430'  
GROUP BY MacID ) B ON  A.MacID = B.MacID 
WHERE DayID between '20180401' and '20180430'  
AND A.MacID in
 ('A06','A07', 'A08', 'A09', 'B01','B05','B09', 'B10', 'B11', 'C04', 'C08', 'C09') 
group by A.MacID, A.EventName) a 
ON A.EVENTNAME = Z.EVENTNAME  and Z.MacID  = a.MacID order by Z.MacID, Z.EventName
Group by Core, Eventname
```

Comment: I get an error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Group'` on the last line.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this, as you need all the required values with sum and condition in single query.

```js
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(name VARCHAR(50), quantity INT, saledate DATE)
INSERT INTO @tbl(name, quantity, saledate)
VALUES('A', 20, '2018-05-31'), ('B', 50, '2018-05-25'), ('c', 40, '2018-05-20'), ('a', 40, '2018-05-10'), ('d', 20, '2018-05-15'), ('c', 20, '2018-05-20')
SELECT a.name, SUM(CASE WHEN a.saledate > '2018-05-15'
  THEN a.quantity ELSE 0 END)
FROM @tbl a
WHERE(a.saledate > '2018-05-15'
  OR a.name in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')) GROUP BY a.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution to the issue, all I had to do was remove MacID from the select functions and declare the EventName:

```
SELECT 'Core' as Core, Z.EventName, ISNULL(DIFF,0) AS DIFF FROM 
(select distinct EventName from dbo.tblMachine a 

join 
(SELECT DISTINCT EVENTNAME FROM dbo.tblEvtDur) b 
on b.EventName <> '' and eventname in ('BLK', 'MDL', 'MTL', 'OFF', 'RPR', 'RUN') 
and MacID in ('A06','A07', 'A08', 'A09', 'B01','B05','B09', 'B10', 'B11', 'C04', 'C08', 'C09')) Z 

LEFT JOIN (SELECT A.EventName, SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, A.STARTdt, A.eNDdt)) as diff, 
round(SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, A.STARTdt, A.eNDdt)) / cast(aVG(Tdiff) as decimal(30,8)),4) * 100 AS PER 
FROM dbo.tblEvtDur  A 

LEFT JOIN ( SELECT EVENTNAME, SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, STARTdt, eNDdt)) as Tdiff 
FROM dbo.tblEvtDur  WHERE DayID between '20180401' and '20180430' GROUP BY EVENTNAME ) B 
ON  A.EVENTNAME = B.EVENTNAME 

WHERE DayID between '20180401' and '20180430' 
AND A.MacID in ('A06','A07', 'A08', 'A09', 'B01','B05','B09', 'B10', 'B11', 'C04', 'C08', 'C09') 
and A.eventname in ('BLK', 'MDL', 'MTL', 'OFF', 'RPR', 'RUN') 
group by A.EventName) a ON A.EVENTNAME = Z.EVENTNAME and Z.EVENTNAME  = a.EVENTNAME order by  Z.EventName
```